# How to draw KDE over Histogram Plot

Tags: r, statistics

I just plotted a histogram on R for some data, following:

```
hist(Y1, breaks=30)
```

I don't know how to draw a Kernel density estimate plot smoothly over the histogram plot.

All suggestion appreciated

Comment: `v <- rchisq(1000, 2); hist(v, prob=T); lines(density(v))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `freq = FALSE` in `hist`.

```
set.seed(1)
Y1 <- rgamma(100, 10, 3)

hist(Y1, breaks = 30, freq = FALSE)
dens <- density(Y1)
lines(dens)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You, so kind of you!! that was the answer I was exactly looking for... Best wishes ....